# Pywinauto - COMError when selecting tabs

Tags: python, excel, ui-automation, pywinauto, comtypes

I've been having a problem lately, when I select specific tabs (sheets) in excel documents, I get the following error:

```
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.pyc in select(self, item)
    402     def select(self, item):
    403         """Select a tab by index or by name"""
--> 404         self._select(item)
    405         return self
    406

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.pyc in _select(self, item)
    604         if item_index < len(list_):
    605             wrp = list_[item_index]
--> 606             wrp.iface_selection_item.Select()
    607         else:
    608             raise IndexError("item not found")

COMError: (-2147467263, 'Not implemented', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

This is the code:

```
app = pywinauto.Application(backend="uia").connect(process=43800)
tab_list = app.top_window().descendants(control_type="Tab")
tab_menu = tab_list[1]
tab_menu.select(1)
```

The excel document has multiple sheets.
The tab window is "*uia_controls.TabControlWrapper - 'Sheet1', TabControl, 3527539*".

It seems that the methods: *get_selected_tab()* and *tab_count()* work. So the only problem is the "*select()*" method which should actually select the tab.

I've tested it on multiple excel files, and in different environments (python2.7, windows 10 and windows 2016, with and without admin privileges)

What can be the problem here? Is there a solution or a workaround to this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `SelectionItemPattern` is not supported by this tab control. As a workaround you can try `.invoke()` for the tab item or `.click_input()` as a last bastion.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thanks.. The .invoke() raises NoPatternInterfaceError. click_input seems to work if the tab is in the boundary of the window.. It's really weird.. A month ago it was working fine, it's probably has something to do with Microsoft updates maybe.